# Character encoding issue when deploying SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I’m using VS2015 with SSDT for developing Integration Services projects for Sql Server 2016. An example of the issue I’m facing when deploying the SSIS package to the sever:

I created a table in a test database (Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EncodingError](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Text] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[TimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then I created a new SSIS project (project deployment model) and added into the default package a Connection Manager for the test db and an “Execute SQL Task” with the script:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EncodingError](Text,TimeStamp) SELECT '¤' AS Text,GETDATE() AS TimeStamp
```

When running the package from VS or deploying the whole project to the server (SSIS catalog) and running the package there, it insert the rows correctly into the table:

```
ID  Text    TimeStamp
1   ¤       2017-09-04 12:13:54.3100000
2   ¤       2017-09-04 12:14:26.2266667
```

When I redeploy - now only the package, not the whole project - to the server and I run it again it inserts the row like this:

```
ID  Text    TimeStamp
3   Â¤      2017-09-04 12:16:16.8866667
```

Now when I again redeploy the whole project it’s working correctly.

After I deployed only the package, I created a new SSIS project with the wizard to import the project back from the server. In this case the script in the task is shown as:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EncodingError](Text,TimeStamp)
SELECT 'Â¤' AS Text
      ,GETDATE() AS TimeStamp
```

Any idea what is the reason for this behavior? What is the difference if I deploy the whole project vs. only the package from the character encoding point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good afternoon

I went through a similar problem and solved it by applying Cumulative Update 6 for SQL Server 2016 SP1

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4037354